# Getting values in XML parsing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I am parsing a XML file and I want to insert the parsed values into the database,I parsed a set of values and placed in a variable "data". Now I want to pick each values from the variable.Can any one help me,I am a newbie?

The code

```
  XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
  var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("returnData")
                   select new fieldvalue
                   {
                       Authenticated = (String)query.Element("authenticated"),
                       Repphoto = (String)query.Element("rep_photo"),
                       Repuname = (String)query.Element("rep_uname"),
                       Repemail = (String)query.Element("rep_email"),
                       Repphone = (String)query.Element("rep_phone"),
                       Repwebsite = (String)query.Element("rep_website"),
                       Userimgsize = (String)query.Element("user_img_size"),
                       Usersigsize = (String)query.Element("user_sig_size")
                     };
```

The class file

```
public class fieldvalue
{
    String authenticated, rep_photo, rep_uname, rep_email, rep_phone, rep_website, user_img_size, user_sig_size;
  public String Authenticated
    {
        get { return authenticated; }
        set { authenticated = value; }
    }
    public String Repphoto
    {
        get { return rep_photo; }
        set { rep_photo = value; }
    }
    public String Repuname
    {
        get { return rep_uname; }
        set { rep_uname = value; }
    }
    public String Repemail
    {
        get { return rep_email; }
        set { rep_email = value; }
    }
    public String Repphone
    {
        get { return rep_phone; }
        set { rep_phone = value; }
    }
    public String Repwebsite
    {
        get { return rep_website; }
        set { rep_website = value; }
    }
    public String Userimgsize
    {
        get { return user_img_size; }
        set { user_img_size = value; }
    }
    public String Usersigsize
    {
        get { return user_sig_size; }
        set { user_sig_size = value; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to pick each values from the variable.

Cast `IEnumerable<fieldvalue>` result to  `ToList<>` and use *index* to access each element.

```
var data = (from query in xdoc.Descendants("returnData")
                   select new fieldvalue
                   {
                       Authenticated = (String)query.Element("authenticated"),
                       Repphoto = (String)query.Element("rep_photo"),
                       Repuname = (String)query.Element("rep_uname"),
                       Repemail = (String)query.Element("rep_email"),
                       Repphone = (String)query.Element("rep_phone"),
                       Repwebsite = (String)query.Element("rep_website"),
                       Userimgsize = (String)query.Element("user_img_size"),
                       Usersigsize = (String)query.Element("user_sig_size")
                     }).ToList();
```

Something like:

```
var name=data[0].Repuname;
```